# Split a list by comma and how to exclude comma and quotations from quotes in split

Tags: python

I have a list of lists. How do I split strings inside a list that contains commas and quotations and then convert them into strings:

The list structure is like this:

```
test_list = [['00000','test', 26.84, 67.8, 14.7, 3.2143838377847933, 'Test 39-64, bot, 8.625" AS', 'NORMAL', 'Wave', 'D'], ['00001','test', 26.84, 67.8, 14.7, 3.2143838377847933, 'Test 39-64, bot, 8.625" AS', 'NORMAL', 'Wave', 'D']]
```

My current implementation gives me the following:

```
'00000,test, 26.84, 67.8, 14.7, 3.2143838377847933, Test 39-64, bot, 8.625" AS, NORMAL, Wave, D'
```

based on the following code:

```
tests = '\n'.join(','.join(map(str, row)) for row in test_list)
```

I want my desired outcome to look like this if possible:

```
' 00000,test, 26.84, 67.8, 14.7, 3.2143838377847933, 'Test 39-64, bot, 8.625" AS, NORMAL', Wave, D
```

I am not sure how to achieve this

Comment: What is your current implementation?

Comment: It's in the question, I added the code @EdekiOkoh

Comment: Is the expected output supposed to be a list ?

Comment: It's suppose to be a string @AlexandreB.

Comment: Your "expected outcome" is a tuple of strings, but the operations you give would result in a single string.  Please correct the posting.

Comment: You confuse the printing representation of your splitted list with what it is. `test` would be a name error if anything at all and `"Test 39-64, bot, 8.625" AS, NORMAL",` is lacking a `"` or a `,` to even be valid python. Please do a [mre].

Comment: Yes; your desired output is not a legal Python sequence.  Also, you're trying to recombine the list item `'Test 39-64, bot, 8.625" AS'`, without ever addressing that change in your code.

Comment: @Prune I fixed the desired ouput

Comment: @PatrickArtner that string format  comes from a file, I am just trying to keep it the same

Comment: No, the desired output is still illegal.  Just try to assign that sequence of characters to a variable name.

Comment: Ok the desired output should just be a string that separates by commas but ignores the commas inside the elements with quotes. I can't assign variable because the data set it too much. @Prune

Comment: @testStackFlow This is looking very much like the rows of a csv file. I suggest you use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv), which automatically deals with quoting issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood well, this may be an option:

```
l = [['00000','test', 26.84, 67.8, 14.7, 3.2143838377847933, 'Test 39-64, bot, 8.625" AS', 'NORMAL', 'Wave', 'D'], ['00001','test', 26.84, 67.8, 14.7, 3.2143838377847933, 'Test 39-64, bot, 8.625" AS', 'NORMAL', 'Wave', 'D']]

for x in l:
    result = ''
    for y in x:
        result += f'"{y}", '

    result = result[:-2]
    print(result)
```

Comment: `print('\n'.join(', '.join(f'"{y}"' for y in x) for x in l))`.

Comment: Yes, much better, closer to question's syntax.